# SBT & Scala AudioSystem

Tags: scala, sbt, specs2

I have a strange problem that I've been trying to figure out for a while now.
I have an application that I am building with Scala & Spray and which uses the AudioSystem API.
I build and test the application using SBT.
I have a boot.scala which extends "App".
If I place the following code in boot.scala and run it through Eclipse(without sbt) (Run As... Scala App) it runs fine...

```
val stream:AudioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("test.wav"))
val audioFormat:AudioFormat = stream.getFormat();
val samplingRate = audioFormat.getSampleRate()
println("Sampling Rate: "+samplingRate)
```

The sampling rate of the file is output as expected.
I have the same code in a Specs2 Route test similar to...

```
"API" should {
  "Respond to POST requests" in {
    val stream:AudioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("test.wav"))
    val audioFormat:AudioFormat = stream.getFormat();
    val samplingRate = audioFormat.getSampleRate()
    println("Sampling Rate: "+samplingRate)
    ...
```

However when I execute this from a terminal using "sbt test" I get the following error...

```
UnsupportedAudioFileException: : could not get audio input stream from input file
```

I know the file (test.wav) is ok as I can play it and executing the code through Eclipse works fine. The terminal (and its encodings) seem ok too as I put together a test file which just runs the same few lines of code and ran it from a terminal successfully.

The problem seems to only occur with SBT!

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone have any ideas at all?!?! Literally pulling my hair out here!

Comment: I also found this page which seems to suggest other people are also having issues accessing the Java Audio API in SBT...

http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-run-scala-application-jar-files-set-classpath?nocache=1#comment-7779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer after literally days of searching...

[Why does AudioSystem.getMixerInfo() return different results under sbt vs Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145198/why-does-audiosystem-getmixerinfo-return-different-results-under-sbt-vs-scala)

"This is a classloader issue. javax.sound does NOT like having the context classloader be anything other than the system classloader." and the fix for me was...

```
val cl = classOf[javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem].getClassLoader
val old = Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader

var audioFormat:AudioFormat = null
try {
  Thread.currentThread.setContextClassLoader(cl)
  val stream:AudioInputStream = 
    AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))
  audioFormat = stream.getFormat()
} finally Thread.currentThread.setContextClassLoader(old)
```

Thanks